# Changesets candidates for merging showing up over and over again

Tags: tfs, merge

I have a main line called "Main" and a "Dev" line. Dev is child of Main.

```
Main
  ^
  |
Dev
```

Actually, Main is used as a normal Dev branch, so both are checked-in new work continuously.

From time to time, we decide to merge both. Pull Dev changesets to Main and the other way around. I guess we've not doing this correctly. We change files during merges, etc. In one situation we have created a branch from Dev to stabilize. Guess this was a mistake.

The problem is, some changesets are "persistents", they keep showing up in merge window, also in "tf merge /candidate" command, as if they weren't merged already.

I guess I could do a tf /discard and that would make the changeset disappear. Shouldn't it be this way?

What is more, sometimes a merge reappers or even disappers after merging another changeset. Guess it is a somehow related changeset from another merge operation. In the course of getting rid of these, one single changeset is merged more than once.

PS: Have tried tf /discard, tf /discard /baseless, tf /baseless handling conflicts. Nothing works. Did not try /force because I'm not keen on redoing all conflicts AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to ne like you are suffering from the pick-n-mix anti pattern.

http://nakedalm.com/avoid-pick-n-mix-branching-anti-pattern/

Change your branching method and the issue will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Since I could not merge in the reverse direction (as mentioned in another solution), I tried to solve this in another way.

I rolled back the merge, checked in, and merged again. This time, trying to make **no invasive changes**.

I did have to 'change' the project file, since the merge tool listed a single chunk of lines that I needed to merge partially. So I excluded the chunk but manually copied the lines that I did need, still inside VS's merge tool, during conflict resolution. Then I accepted the resolution.

During my first attempt, I had left out these lines completely, causing some files and folders to be wrongfully excluded from the project. Then, in the Solution Explorer, I had re-included those files and folders.

Somehow it seems that my first attempt caused TFS to see the merge as incomplete, leaving it in the list. **My second attempt was seen as a complete merge and successfully swallowed the candidate.**

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need to discard changesets.  If you want to "sync" them, just merge MAIN->DEV, then DEV->MAIN, potentially resolving conflicts at both steps.

After that no changesets should show up in the merge list and they should be in sync.  If this isn't happening for you, we need some kind of reproducible scenario or detailed description of a specific scenario so we can help you out.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce this. Some hints to find out what's happenning would be helpful. I'm doing discard because the merge was already apllied, so I'm interested in getting that changesets out of sight.